# Auto Form Fill and Submit on new page

Tags: javascript, testing, google-chrome-extension

I want to know that is it possible to make a chrome extension or a script that can fill the form input field and submit it and the result open on a new page. and then again the next value is added to the form and it is submitted.
the input text numbers and it increased after form submission. for example, the first input was 1 and then it is submitted, and after that 2 was inserted in the input field and it is searched and so on. in short for Loop.
Can anyone tell me the solution or a way to do it?

I dont know how to do it I want to know if someone made the auto form filler and submitter and result on a new page.

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.